# How to store value from observable via subscribe to variable inside component - Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to store value from observable to a variable inside the component using a service however it always has the value of undefined. "names" inside subscribe contains value as expected.

```js
this.dataClient.obsNames.subscribe(names => {
      
      this.names = names; //declared above as public names = [];
     
    });
```

Comment: how is the variable  names defined in component?

Comment: @amrit it is declared as `public names = [];` ... i have also tried changing it's access type to private and it still didn't help

Comment: try it defining like names :any

Comment: why did you decide that `this.names` is not actually set to `obsNames` payload? How exactly you checked that?

Comment: @SergeyP.akaazure i check it using the built-in debugger in chrome and in visual studio code

Comment: @caricature and where EXACTLY was the breakpoint where you checked the value? At what moment you stopped there? Was it before assignment in subscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i think you have print this.names on console outside of subscribe.which is asynchronous method.due to which your getting undefined.

Try this:

```
 `this.dataClient.obsNames.subscribe(names =>{ 
      this.names = names;
      console.log(this.names);
  });`
```